# How to output a multidimensional list with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert this first multidimensional array to the second one:

```
[[1,4,7], [3,6,2], [2,5,9], [88,6,1]]
```

to

```
[[88,2,3,1], [6,5,6,4], [1,9,2,7]]
```

I wrote this function

```
def rotate(myList):
    newList = []
    reverseList = list(reversed(myList))
    for subList in reverseList:
        newList.append(subList[0])
    print(newList)

rotate([[1,4,7], [3,6,2], [2,5,9], [88,6,1]])
```

This outputs

```
[88, 2, 3, 1]
```

I reverse the multidimensional list, and for each sublist in the reversed multidimensional list, I append the first element to a new list called newList.

This is a good start, but it is not complete. How would one output the rest of the lists? I don't know how to output multiple lists to a new multidimensional list in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip()` is your friend.

```
def rotate(mylist):
    return list(zip(*mylist[::-1]))
```

This reverses `mylist`, sends each sublist to `zip()`, and turns that into a `list`.

```
>>> rotate([[1,4,7], [3,6,2], [2,5,9], [88,6,1]])
[(88, 2, 3, 1), (6, 5, 6, 4), (1, 9, 2, 7)]
```

Comment: I didn't know about zip. This is a perfect solution. I will accept answer when time limit allows it. Thanks

Comment: I have to ask, what does the * do?

Comment: @PencilCrate - It unpacks the iterable and sends each element as a separate argument. Try `print([1, 2, 3])` and `print(*[1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating an empty multidimensional array with the number of lines and columns you desire the output to have, and then fill it with the values of the transposition of the original matrix.

```
    def rotate(A, m, n):
        A = A[::-1]
        C = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                C[j][i] = A[i][j]
        return C
```

Comment: What's wrong with populating it on creation? And you should probably keep the same method signature, and just calculate `m` and `n` automatically. `def rotate(A): return [[A[::-1][j][i] for j in range(len(A))] for i in range(len(A[0]))]`.